# What values to benchmark and check over the complex plane for a math function?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, testing, complex-numbers

Consider a C complex mathematical function `cfunction(z)` which takes a complex argument `z=x+iy`. I would like to run an automatic test to check the result of this function over the complex plane.

To do so, a script will print the result of this function for a matrix of values: for example all combinations for `x in [-inf, 0, inf]` and `y in [-inf, 0, inf]`.

So if I perform this test for `x in [list]` and `y in [list]`, what values should I put in `[list]` to check the validity of the function over the complex plane efficiently ?

I think of something like that: `list = [-inf, -1., -0., 0., 1., +inf, NaN]`, but I assume that this kind of checking is a well known problem and some libraries may have solved this issue with a more exhaustive approach.

Remark: I consider that the function does not have any property of symmetry or particular values.

Comment: You want to "check the validity over the complex plane". What does that mean? That cfunction(z) actually returns a complex number (and not a runtime exception) for all z? There are an infinite number of points to check, so you can't check them all. For the ones you do test, how do you "check" them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas too big for a comment.

To your list: `list = [-inf, -1., -0., 0., 1., +inf, NaN]`, one may add:

A random set (maybe 100s)
Generate by filling the `u64` field in the following `union`, and toss out non-finite numbers.

Classic constants

```
M_PI
e
```

More special values

```
union {
  uint64_t u64;
  double d;
} sNaN, qNan;
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QNaN#Signaling_NaN
sNaN.u64 = 0x7ff0000000000001;
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QNaN#Quiet_NaN
qNaN.u64 = 0x7ff1000000000000;
// Max/Min float
DBL_MAX;    
-DBL_MAX;    
// Small
DBL_MIN
DBL_TRUE_MIN
//
OnePLus = 1.0 + DBL_EPSILON;
```